# Extend UICollectionView header content to reach below first cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Following is the effect I want to achieve, extending the content of header to reach below the first cell. I tried to set the image size larger than the header and set `clipsToBounds` to false. However, the image goes on top of the cell and covers it. Is there a way to move the image below the cell?

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you need it to be a UITableView header because it will scroll off when you get to another Section?  And not just a fixed view behind the tableview that never moves?

Comment: It's supposed to move off screen, it's just a section header and there are multiple sections in the view

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`. If anyone is interested, let me know, I can post my code here

Comment: Sorry, sent you code for accomplishing this in a TableView.  Check my updated answer below which will do the same thing for a UICollectionView.  If you only need to have it be behind the cells, it is a much simpler change than subclassing the UICollectionViewFlowLayout.  However, if you plan to do more flow manipulation, I would stick with the subclassing approach

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting the zPosition of the layer in the `willDisplayXXX` methods.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplaySupplementaryView:(UICollectionReusableView *)view forElementKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    view.layer.zPosition = 0.0;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.layer.zPosition = 99 + indexPath.row;
}
```

Similarly, you can accomlplish this in a `UITableView` by using the `willDisplayHeaderView` and `willDisplayCell` methods.  Basically, set the header to a low value and the cell to a higher value, and it should put the cells in front of the header.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    view.layer.zPosition = 0.0;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(MyCustomCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.layer.zPosition = 99 + indexPath.row;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had said you were using a UITableView.  The above code clearly won't work for a UICollectionView.  But with a simple change, it will work for a collectionview in the same way, much easier than subclassing UICollectionFlowLayout.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: This approach has the problem that as soon as the header is going off screen, the part of the image that is under the cell suddenly disappears. There looks like to have no way around it except subclassing layout

Comment: Ah, I have my collection view extend up under a translucent nav bar, so I didn't notice that.  You could look to have the tableview extend up past the top of the screen the height of your header view, and then add an inset to offset the area off the screen.  In theory it will work, but since you have it working with a subclass, it's probably best to use what you have.